# Open .csv file with Python throws NameError

Tags: python

I'm following an example in a book and receiving an error. I have two files. One is named nobel_winners.csv and the other test.py I am trying to open nobel_winners.csv from test.py.

The contents of nobel_winners.csv is:

```
nobel_winners = [
 {'category': 'Physics',
  'name': 'Albert Einstein',
  'nationality': 'Swiss',
  'sex': 'male',
  'year': 1921},
 {'category': 'Physics',
  'name': 'Paul Dirac',
  'nationality': 'British',
  'sex': 'male',
  'year': 1933},
 {'category': 'Chemistry',
  'name': 'Marie Curie',
  'nationality': 'Polish',
  'sex': 'female',
  'year': 1911}
]
```

from my test.py, I'm using `f = open('nobel_winners.csv', 'w')` then `cols =  nobel_winners[0].keys()`. The program then throws:

> NameError: name 'nobel_winners' is not defined.

What is going awry here?

Comment: Why is that file named as a .csv? Also, it seems like that file is a valid Python list of dictionaries? Can you control the name of the file? Because then you can make it a .py and just import it and use it directly as a valid Python data structure.

Comment: When you say `cols =  nobel_winners[0].keys()` what is `nobel_winners` assigned with? You might not have defined that variable going by the error.

Comment: your `nobel_winners.csv` is not CSV file but normal Python file. Rename it into `nobel_winners.py` and import `from nobel_winners import *`

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because the variable 'nobel_winners' is not defined before you call it.

I'm not aware with your code but if you are reading from csv, the code below works for me. This my not be the best way though. I did it with some guidance from a question posted here in this site.

```
def read_from_csv(filename,nrows,ncols):
csv_data = np.zeros((nrows,ncols))

with open(filename,'rb') as csvfile:
  read_csv = csv.reader(csvfile)
  i=0
  for row in read_csv:
      csv_data[i] = np.array(row)
      csv_data[i] = csv_data[i].astype(np.float)
      i += 1
csvfile.close()
return csv_data
```

Answer (score 0):

You have f = the opening of the file, but do not have nobel_winners  referenced as a variable before you call it with cols =

Ensure you set the variable before assigning it in another variable.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things that are incorrect in your code.

- The input file is not a csv. It has a variable = list of dictionaries
  format. Convert your input file format to a JSON. And try to read the
  JSON data in your code.
- You are opening the file in write mode and
  trying to read it. The reason for the `NameError` is because you are
  hoping that the `nobel_winners` in the input file will be converted
  to a variable in your code. Which it will not.

That said to get your current input file and the code to work, you can redefine your input file as

```
[
 {'category': 'Physics',
  'name': 'Albert Einstein',
  'nationality': 'Swiss',
  'sex': 'male',
  'year': '1921'},
 {'category': 'Physics',
  'name': 'Paul Dirac',
  'nationality': 'British',
  'sex': 'male',
  'year': '1933'},
 {'category': 'Chemistry',
  'name': 'Marie Curie',
  'nationality': 'Polish',
  'sex': 'female',
  'year': '1911'}
]
```

and then use the following code

```
import ast
with open('data.csv', 'r') as myfile:
    data = myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
data_dict = ast.literal_eval(data)
cols =  data_dict[0].keys()
```

Or as furas suggested in the comments, treat the input file as a regular python file instead of a csv file (rename it to .py). That way you would have to change your code to:

```
from nobel_winners import nobel_winners
cols =  nobel_winners[0].keys()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the data within the code in one file, test.py.  The script writes to file data/nobel_winners.csv.  The correct script is this:

```
f = open('data/nobel_winners.csv', 'w')

nobel_winners = [
 {'category': 'Physics',
  'name': 'Albert Einstein',
  'nationality': 'Swiss',
  'sex': 'male',
  'year': 1921},
 {'category': 'Physics',
  'name': 'Paul Dirac',
  'nationality': 'British',
  'sex': 'male',
  'year': 1933},
 {'category': 'Chemistry',
  'name': 'Marie Curie',
  'nationality': 'Polish',
  'sex': 'female',
  'year': 1911}
]

cols = nobel_winners[0].keys()
cols.sort()

with open('data/nobel_winners.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(','.join(cols) + '\n')

    for o in nobel_winners:
      row = [str(o[col]) for col in cols]
      f.write(','.join(row) + '\n')

 with open('data/nobel_winners.csv') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print(line),
```